# How to cache / replay result of intermediate steps with RxJava Observable while being able to cancel and resume in the middle?

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming

My goal is to perform multiple steps of action, for example:

1. Get token.
2. Use token to initialize API.
3. Once API is initialized, start observing data.

The tricky part here is that I also have a `mStateChangeObservable` that emit on and off signals (e.g. wifi on or off), and I should be able to cancel the sequence of actions in the middle, but every time, signal is "on", I should not restart from beginning. Currently I was able to achieve this using below code, but this is just hard to maintain. I'm looking for a more elegant way to achieve this using Rx operators.

Anything prefixed with `m` is a member variable of the class instance.

```
mStateChangeObservable = new StateChange().getObservable().replay(1).refCount();

Observable<String> dataObservable =
    Single.<Api>create(
            emitter -> {
              if (mToken == null) {
                emitter.setDisposable(
                    getToken()
                        .subscribe(
                            token -> {
                              mToken = token;

                              emitter.setDisposable(
                                  getApi()
                                      .subscribe(
                                          api -> {
                                            mApi = api;
                                            emitter.onSuccess(mApi);
                                          }));
                            }));
              } else if (mApi == null) {
                emitter.setDisposable(
                    getApi()
                        .subscribe(
                            api -> {
                              mApi = api;
                              emitter.onSuccess(mApi);
                            }));
              } else {
                emitter.onSuccess(mApi);
              }
            })
        .flatMapObservable(Api::getDataObservable);

mDataDisposable =
    mStateChangeObservable
        .switchMap(
            isReady -> {
              Log.d(TAG, "#1 Is ready = " + isReady);

              if (isReady) {
                return dataObservable;
              } else {
                return Observable.never();
              }
            })
        .subscribe(data -> Log.d(TAG, "api data = " + data));
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a slightly more elegant way, but would still prefer if someone has a better way:

```
mStateChangeObservable = new StateChange().getObservable().replay(1).refCount();

Observable<String> dataObservable =
    Single.defer(
            () -> {
              if (mToken == null) {
                return getToken().doOnSuccess(token -> mToken = token);
              } else {
                return Single.just(mToken);
              }
            })
        .flatMap(
            token -> {
              if (mApi == null) {
                return getApi().doOnSuccess(api -> mApi = api);
              } else {
                return Single.just(mApi);
              }
            })
        .flatMapObservable(Api::getDataObservable);

mDataDisposable =
    mStateChangeObservable
        .switchMap(
            isReady -> {
              Log.d(TAG, "#1 Is ready = " + isReady);

              if (isReady) {
                return dataObservable;
              } else {
                return Observable.never();
              }
            })
        .subscribe(data -> Log.d(TAG, "api data = " + data));
```